# behat3: @beforestep. Is it possible to change actual step text here from within function

Tags: php, bdd, behat

behat3: @beforestep. 
Is it possible to alter actual step definition text here from within function.

I can see a getStep->getText

But no SetText.

I want to create a timestam and some random string  to one of the fields in the request.

Comment: And i want the new output in the output when run on command line not the original table entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so.

The step definition must match a regular expression.What you are seeing in getStep->getText is after the step has been already parsed.

When the scenario executes it will search to match the steps by regex, if you could alter the step definition then then regex will not find any match.

In this case you need to create a custom step or extend the current method and add an if for a specific parameter to append the time stamp.
Second option is not recommended since you will alter a general step/method.

A good option would be to use page object if you are not using and create a custom step there.